# how to open window in new tab with javascript without changing browser settings

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I want to open window in new tab with javascript without changing browser settings

Below is the piece of code i ave written.. bt for that i need to change IE settings to "internet explorer decide how pop-ups should be open"

```
function open_in_new_tab(url)
{   
window.open(url,'_blank');
}
```

Comment: `window.open()` is a bit old fashioned, why don't you use modals?

Comment: Take a look at the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function open_in_new_tab(url )
{
  var win=window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}
```

[Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not possible to open a window in a new tab instead of a new window without changing browser settings.